# Ruby on Rails passing variable from View to Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, parameters, null

I have this on the view:

```
th = link_to "ID", :search_form => @search_form
```

and this on the Controller:

```
@search_form = params[:search_form]
```

On the debugger no parameter :search_form is displayed and on the program it leads to a nil error while on the controller there is an actual declared @search_form variable. Why is it empty on the Controller ?

Comment: Please show more code e.g. the controller method. Also the link_to doesn't appear to be formatted correctly, where is it posting to?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a path in your `link_to`

```
= link_to 'ID', some_path(search_form: @search_form)
```

alternatively you can specify the controller and action like this

```
= link_to 'ID', url_for(controller: :some_controller, action: :show, search_form: @search_form)
```

Comment: How can I specify a path to a controller ?

Comment: Either by doing the `url_for(controller: my_controller ....)` Iceman suggested, or using rails' routes auto-naming. It generates a shortcut for most routes. For example to access the `show` action of your controller `my_controller` the route would be: `show_my_controller_path`

Comment: You specify a path in your `routes.rb` file. Can read about that in the rails guides on routing.

Comment: So if I first render them from the @search_form instance,  for example like that: `#{@search_form.id}` and then I just want to get them back to the controller with the `url_for` method for example ... why are they nil? Does that mean once the view has been displayed every variable deleted?

Comment: They are not deleted once displayed.